# Create a .txt file and store it on a specific folder Laravel

Tags: laravel

So basicly, I have to make a Laravel command which will create a .txt file. The command accepts as arguments the index of the file(id) and one or more tokens(words inside file). I am finding unable to create the file with it's content inside my desired folder(Called 'files' inside the root directory).
I found a way to create it inside the Storage, but that's not exactly what i need.
Would appreciate some help, thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check out the `filesystems.php` file and maybe add a configuration for the directory you want. After doing so, you will be able to create a file using the File facade and specifying your disk like so: `File::disk('my-disk')`

Comment: @ettdro thankyou, that's what i needed. You can post the answer as a comment so i can mark it as `solved`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `filesystems.php` file and add a specific configuration for the directory you want to read/write. After doing so, you will be able to create a file using the File facade by specifying your disk like so: `File::disk('my-disk')`.